# how to mirror input type=file

Tags: javascript, mirror, input-type-file

Is it possible after selecting the file for pic1 below to have the selected file automatically mirrored into a second form field? 
I'm just starting to learn javascript - how would I go about doing this?
details please - thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793990/set-input-file-value-to-second-input-file#16794278

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this ‒ as a security precaution, no website can define a value for an `<input type="file" />`, and no script can set a value to it, either (you get an `Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11`).

All is not lost, however, as you can access a user selected file with *JavaScript* and store it elsewhere in memory to use later. The [*HTMLInputElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) DOM interface gives you a property `files` (a [*FileList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)), which lets you access selected items as [*File*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) instances, which in turn can be interpreted like a *Blob* through an instance of [*FileReader*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

*FileReader* gives you the choice of

- readAsArrayBuffer
- readAsBinaryString
- readAsDataURL
- readAsText

For [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9pV6/), if you wanted to store the data as a *dataURI*,

```
var myInputElement = document.getElementById('pic1'); // the <input />
// assuming file already chosen
var fr = new FileReader(); // instance of FileReader
fr.onload = function (e) { // task to do when finished reading file
    console.log(this.result); // view in console
};
fr.readAsDataURL(myInputElement.files.item(0)); // start read
```